# how to fix configuration not found in guava error

Tags: java, xml, ant, guava, ivy

I have tried to resolve dependencies from local filesystem; to do so, I have wrote ivy.xml, ivyconf.xml and build.xml. However, my scripts donot work and couldnot resolve dependencies i.e. couldnot find jar files. What is the problem behind it? And, how can I solve it?

error

```
Error
[ivy:resolve] com.google.guava#guava;17.0: configuration not found in
              com.google.guava#guava;17.0: 'public'. It was required from 
              .. runtime
```

project hierarchy

```
project
  | - - src
  | - - lib
         | - - guava.jar
  | - - conf
         | - - ant
                | - - build.xml
         | - - ivy
                | - - ivy.xml
                | - - ivyconf.xml
```

ivy.xml file

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <configurations defaultconfmapping="runtime->public">
        <conf   name="compile"      visibility="private"/>
        <conf   name="jar"
                extends="compile"       
                visibility="private"/>

        <conf   name="runtime"      
                extends="jar"   
                visibility="public"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.google.guava"  name="guava"    rev="17.0"  conf="runtime->public"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

lastly, ivyconf.xml

```
<conf   defaultresolver="local"/>
<resolves>
        <filesystem name="local">
            <artifact   pattern="${lib.dir}/**/*.jar" />
        </filesystem>
</resolves>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ivy configuration file is invalid ("resolvers" not "resolves"). Additionally you're going to have problems with dependency versioning if the jar file does not contain a version in the filename.

My suggestion is to use the following ivy configuration file:

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver='central' />
  <resolvers>
    <ibiblio name='central' m2compatible='true'/>
    <filesystem name='local'>
      <artifact pattern='${ivy.settings.dir}/../../lib/[artifact]' />
    </filesystem>
  </resolvers>
  <modules>
    <module organisation='NA' resolver='local' />
  </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

You'll then have a choice of declaring your dependencies as follows:

```
<dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="17.0" />

<dependency org="NA"  name="guava" rev="NA"  conf="runtime->default"/>
```

The first will retrieve from the [Maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.guava%7Cguava%7C17.0%7Cbundle), the second will retrieve from your local filesystem.

See the following answers for more examples of this approach:

- [IVY Build, how do I use an extlib directory in the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734368/ivy-build-how-do-i-use-an-extlib-directory-in-the-project/21738077#21738077)
- [Ivy dependency management for legacy repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182908/ivy-dependency-management-for-legacy-repository/19196011#19196011)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should I put <ivysettings> in settings file or ivyconf? In book, ant in action, it says if you do local project you should create ivyconf instead of settings. I am a bit confused? If I have write ivyconf.xml, should I write some statement so that ivy.xml knows ivyconf.xml is created and settings are stored in it?

Comment: even ivyde gives the same error; is my ivy.xml wrong?

Comment: I am boring you, forgive me. Last question, do I have to implement settings file?

Comment: @Hevan Don't think I understand your question. Please check my second link for a more complete example of using ivy. Personally I always put the build.xml, ivy.xml and ivysettings.xml file in the root dir of my project. Lot simpler and is the default setup for ivy.

Answer (score 0):

I was sure my ivy configuration was right and I still kept getting the error. I am not sure how but my IVY cache was messed up. Clearing the cache (I used rm -rf) and running the build again do it.