# How to give url of folder to ivy pattern

Tags: java, ant, ivy

In ivyconf.xml, I have `pattern='${ivy.settings.dir}/../../lib/Google Guava/[artifact].[ext]' />`. As you can see, I have wrote `Google Guava` in the pattern. However, I have more than one jar file stored in another folder in same level of `Google Guava` folder.

I have tried `**` in place of `Google Guava`, but I think it is not supported in ivyconf.xml. What should I wrote instead of `Google Guava` so that it searches all folders to resolve dependencies?

ivyconf.xml

```
    <resolvers>
        <filesystem name="local">
            <artifact   
                    pattern='${ivy.settings.dir}/../../lib/Google Guava/[artifact].[ext]' />
        </filesystem>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <module organisation='FS' resolver='local' />
    </modules>
```

project structure

```
project
  | - - - src
          ...
  | - - - lib
           | - - Google Guava
                     | - - guava.jar
           | - - Folee
                     | - - folee-1.4.0.jar
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to fix configuration not found in guava error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505746/how-to-fix-configuration-not-found-in-guava-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found how to solve it.

Firstly, I have changed the ivy.xml like;

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="Google Guava"  name="guava"    rev="17.0"  
                conf="compile->default"/>       
    <dependency org="Folee" name="folee-1.4.0"  rev="1.4.0" 
                conf="compile->default"/>       
</dependencies>
```

Then, I have changed the ivyconf.xml like;

```
<conf   defaultresolver="local"/>
<resolvers>
        <filesystem name="local">
            <artifact   
                pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/../../lib/[organisation]/[artifact].[ext]" />
        </filesystem>
</resolvers>
<modules>
    <module resolver="local" />
</modules>
```

As you see, I havenot use `organisation="FS"` to resolve them in own filesystem. Then, I used `organisation` variable as container for storing folder name.

At last, what I got is the clean project hierarchy.